# Axes incorrectly generated using Plot

Tags: plotting

I'm working with the code from the Riemann Sums Wolfram Demonstration.  I'm modifying some of the functions linked to in the controls.  When I do this, in certain cases the axes don't generate correctly.  For example, when I change x-1 to x+1.  Code is below and screenshot of the incorrect graphical rendering is attached.  Any suggestions on where the problem might lie?

```
Manipulate[
 RiemannBlocks[FunctionF[x][[fff]], {x, 0, 5, blocks}, 
  type], {{blocks, 39, "number of rectangles"}, 4, 70, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
   {{type, 2, "height"}, {1 -> "left", 2 -> "midpoint", 
   3 -> "right"}}, {{fff, 4, "function"}, {1 -> "x - 1", 
   2 -> "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\) + 1", 
       3 -> "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(3\)]\) - 1", 
   4 -> "log( x + 1 )", 
   5 -> "( 1 - x \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\()\), \(2\)]\)", 
   6 -> "\[LeftBracketingBar] x - 2 \[RightBracketingBar]", 
   7 -> "cos( x )", 
       8 -> 
    "\!\(\*SqrtBox[\(\[LeftBracketingBar]\\ x - \
1\[RightBracketingBar]\)]\)"}, ControlType -> Setter}, 
 ControllerLinking -> True, 
   Initialization :> {RiemannBlocks[f_, {x_, a_, b_, n_}, type_] := 
    Plot[f, {x, a, b}, 

     Prolog -> Table[({{RGBColor[0.2, 0.5, 0.79], Polygon[#1]}, 
           Line[Append[#1, #1[[1]]]]} & )[(BlockCoords[#1, #2, 
            Sample[f, {x, #1, #2}, type]] & )[a + i*((b - a)/n), 
                   a + (i + 1)*((b - a)/n)]], {i, 0, n - 1}], 
     ImagePadding -> {{25, 25}, {25, 50}}, 

     PlotLabel -> 
      StringJoin["estimated area = ", 
       ToString[
        NumberForm[(b - 
            a)*(Sum[
             IsReal[Sample[
               f, {x, a + i*((b - a)/n), a + (i + 1)*((b - a)/n)}, 
               type]], {i, 0, n - 1}]/n), 
                   {7, 4}, NumberPadding -> {"", "0"}]], "\n", 
       "actual area = ", 
       ToString[
        NumberForm[
         Check[Chop[NIntegrate[f, {x, a, b}, AccuracyGoal -> 12]], 
          I], {7, 4}, 
                   NumberPadding -> {"", "0"}]]]], 
   BlockCoords[a_, b_, h_] := {{a, 0}, {a, h}, {b, h}, {b, 0}}, 
   Sample[f_, {x_, a_, b_}, type_] := 
         {LeftValue[f, {x, a, b}], MidpointValue[f, {x, a, b}], 
      RightValue[f, {x, a, b}]}[[type]], 
   LeftValue[f_, {x_, a_, b_}] := N[f /. x -> a], 
       MidpointValue[f_, {x_, a_, b_}] := N[f /. x -> (a + b)/2], 
   RightValue[f_, {x_, a_, b_}] := N[f /. x -> b], 
       IsReal[x_] := 
    Module[{}, 
     If[ ! NumericQ[x] || Im[x] != 0, 
      Throw["One or more samples are outside the domain."]]; x], 
       FunctionF[x_] := {x - 1, x^2 + 1, x^3 - 1, 
     Log[x + 1], (1 - x)^2, Abs[x - 2], Cos[x], Sqrt[Abs[x - 1]]}}]
```

[image: Incorrect axis]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the y-range of the curve in `Plot` is different than the rectangles drawn in the `Prolog`.

The fix I tried was to move the computation of the polygons outside of `Prolog` into a module. Define a variable, `ymin` to represent the minimum of the polygons and zero.

Set the `AxesOrigin` y-value to `ymin`.

I did not thoroughly test but at least it works for the `x+1 case and you should be able to tweak it from there.

```
Manipulate[
 RiemannBlocks[FunctionF[x][[fff]], {x, 0, 5, blocks}, type],

 {{blocks, 39, "number of rectangles"}, 4, 70, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{type, 2, "height"}, {1 -> "left", 
   2 -> "midpoint", 3 -> "right"}}, {{fff, 4, "function"},
  {1 -> "x + 1", 2 -> "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\) + 1", 
   3 -> "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(3\)]\) - 1", 
   4 -> "log( x + 1 )", 
   5 -> "( 1 - x \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\()\), \(2\)]\)", 
   6 -> "\[LeftBracketingBar] x - 2 \[RightBracketingBar]", 
   7 -> "cos( x )", 
   8 -> "\!\(\*SqrtBox[\(\[LeftBracketingBar]\\ x - 1\
\[RightBracketingBar]\)]\)"}, ControlType -> Setter},

 ControllerLinking -> True,

 Initialization :> {
   RiemannBlocks[f_, {x_, a_, b_, n_}, type_] :=
    Module[
     {
      table = 
       Table[({{RGBColor[0.2, 0.5, 0.79], Polygon[#1]}, 
            Line[Append[#1, #1[[1]]]]} &)[(BlockCoords[#1, #2, 
             Sample[f, {x, #1, #2}, type]] &)[a + i*((b - a)/n), 
          a + (i + 1)*((b - a)/n)]], {i, 0, n - 1}],
      ymin
      },
     ymin = Min[Cases[table, {x_, y_Real} :> y, Infinity]];
     ymin = Min[0, ymin];
     Show[
      Plot[f, {x, a, b},
       AxesOrigin -> {0, ymin},
       ImagePadding -> {{25, 25}, {25, 50}}, 
       PlotLabel -> 
        StringJoin["estimated area = ", 
         ToString[
          NumberForm[(b - 
              a)*(Sum[
               IsReal[Sample[
                 f, {x, a + i*((b - a)/n), a + (i + 1)*((b - a)/n)}, 
                 type]], {i, 0, n - 1}]/n), {7, 4}, 
           NumberPadding -> {"", "0"}]], "\n", "actual area = ", 
         ToString[
          NumberForm[
           Check[Chop[NIntegrate[f, {x, a, b}, AccuracyGoal -> 12]], 
            I], {7, 4}, NumberPadding -> {"", "0"}]]]],
      Graphics[
       table
       ]
      ]
     ],

   BlockCoords[a_, b_, h_] := {{a, 0}, {a, h}, {b, h}, {b, 0}},

   Sample[f_, {x_, a_, b_}, 
     type_] := {LeftValue[f, {x, a, b}], MidpointValue[f, {x, a, b}], 
      RightValue[f, {x, a, b}]}[[type]],

   LeftValue[f_, {x_, a_, b_}] := N[f /. x -> a],

   MidpointValue[f_, {x_, a_, b_}] := N[f /. x -> (a + b)/2],

   RightValue[f_, {x_, a_, b_}] := N[f /. x -> b],

   IsReal[x_] := 
    Module[{}, 
     If[! NumericQ[x] || Im[x] != 0, 
      Throw["One or more samples are outside the domain."]]; x],

   FunctionF[x_] := {x + 1, x^2 + 1, x^3 - 1, Log[x + 1], (1 - x)^2, 
     Abs[x - 2], Cos[x], Sqrt[Abs[x - 1]]}
   }
 ]
```

(* Don't ask my why the red color, works fine in the notebook *)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you so much!  I tested it further and it appears to be fixed for my purposes.  I really appreciate the help!